# Why is my recursive function local variables not resetting after each call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I have this set of code in my node.js function (well this is a much-simplified version). I run `buildWorkout()` and it will call the recursive function `createWorokout()` which in turn calls it's self a few times and then passes the resulting workout back to the callback from `buildWorkout()`.

The issue is if I run `buildWorkout()` again, the `vars.workout` variable will contain the exact data from the last time I ran it, therefore the function just adds to it.

Very strange, I don't often take a recursive approach and I believe thats where my mistake is. How should I fix my code?

```
var buildWorkout = function( pool, cb ) {
    var vars = null

    var vars = {
        workout: config.warmup,
        numOfExercises: 4
    }

    return createWorkout( pool, vars, cb )
}

var createWorkout = function( pool, vars, cb ) {

    sqlCall( pool, function( exercise ) {
        if ( exercise == null ) {
            createWorkout( pool, vars, cb )
        } else {
            vars.workout.push( exercise )

            if ( vars.workout.length = vars.numOfExercises ){
                return cb( vars.workout ) //call callback with return value
            } else {
                return createWorkout( pool, vars, cb ) //recurssion
            }
        }
    } )

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `vars.workout.length = vars.numOfExercises` be `vars.workout.length == vars.numOfExercises` instead?

Comment: you are passing `vars` as a parameter and `vars` only seems to get data pushed, nothing else seems to change

Comment: Objects are passed by a copy of the reference, `vars` refers to the object defined in `buildWorkout` all the time during the execution.

Comment: Recursivity is not the culprit here. `vars.workout` is referring to `config.warmup`. I assume it is an array defined in the global score. So, it's not reseted between 2 calls of buildWorkout. It's rather updated each time.

Comment: If you want to _initialize_ vars.workout with config.warmup, you should use `workout: config.warmup.slice()` instead.

Comment: @Arnauld Thankyou. That appears to be the culprit. Logging it's value between call's shows data is being added to it. Confusing though, because I'm not sure where im appending data to it. Is it because I'm passing a reference?

Comment: @Arnauld That would work in the case `config.warmup` would contain primitives only. `slice` will copy objects by a reference too.

Comment: @arnold the .slice() worked. Is this the best approach? Is there a cleaner way to copy the value of an object in JS instead of the pointer.

Comment: @user3221132 It depends on what config.warmup is made of. IMHO, yes, this is the best approach as long as it is a simple array of primitives. Please see Teemu's warning about encapsulated references, though.

Comment: Once `createWorkout` is invoked from within `buildWorkout`, `buildWorkout` won't be invoked again. When `sqlCall` is called, it immediately returns, because it is a non-blocking function. `createWorkout` returns just undefined and so do `buildWorkout`.